# Related to Code Optimization

Tags: java, loops, optimization, nested

I have came across a question but I'm unable to optimize my code. Please tell me how can I optimize my code.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max=0;
    int a = in.nextInt();
    for(int i=1;i<a;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=a;j++)
        {
            int d = i^j;
            if(d>max)
                max=d;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

The explanation for the above code is:

- The Xor of 1 and 2 is 3.
- The Xor of 1 and 3 is 2.
- The Xor of 2 and 3 is 1.

So, the maximum is 3.

Comment: And what is that question you came across, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: output = Math.pow(2, Math.floor(Math.log2(input) + 1)) - 1

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the maximum you're looking for is all ones in a binary string of length of the binary string that represents your input value.

Your input value is 3, in binary it's '11', xor table:

```
0 xor 0 = 0
1 xor 0 = 1
0 xor 1 = 1
1 xor 1 = 0
```

so what you want is to xor the input value with the opposite value. Here the opposite value is the value with all bytes flipped.

In your example the length of the binary string is 2, so you need to get 2 ones. To achieve that you xor '10' and '01' or '01' and '10' and that's how you get 3.

But you can simply take the opposite of '11' which is '00' and xor those two and get 3 as well (as in the algorithm I described).

I have no idea how to flip a bit string of given length because the '~' operator will flip all 32 bits of an int, but alternatively you can implement it this way:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        for(int i = 1; i < a; ++i) {
            a |= i;
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Now your running time is linear and not quadratic, however you can also achieve the same result by doing:

```
1 << (int)(Math.log(a)/Math.log(2)) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Max = " + Double.toString(Math.pow(2, 1+Math.floor(Math.log(a)/Math.log(2)))-1.0));
```

Oops..  Doesn't work when `a=0`, but you should be able to adjust for that.

### Explanation

For each possible input `a`, there is a number between `1` and `a` that equals `not a` (considering only as many binary digits as are in `a` itself).  So, the max will always equal `(2^n)-1`, where `n` is the number of binary digits in `a`.